# Should I hard-wire only three, of many, smoke-alarms or wirelessly interconnect all of them on batteries?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, smoke-detectors

My local inspector has given me the option to install battery-operated smoke detectors, but he says they must be interconnected.

He would prefer that I run wires and put at least one hard-wired detector on each floor, and in a perfect world, all of the detectors in the house would be hard-wired to each other, but unfortunately, this is impractical without greatly expanding the scope of my original project.

The problem with hard-wiring, is that he is only requiring smoke detectors because I have completed gutted a room and have access to a lot of areas to run wires in that limited region of the house, and I cannot access every room in the same way.  So he basically says, just hardwire where you can, or I can just go all wireless, but he prefers me to wire -- **he isn't being staunch about the hard-wiring and isn't making it a hard requirement**, but he is requiring that I install interconnected smoke detectors, even if they are only on batteries.

The problem with me opting to go with my inspector's preference is that it means **most rooms would be wireless, while three would be wired, and I think this creates two separate groups of detectors that talk to each other, but not across both groups,** unless of course there is a product that is compatible with being wired or not wired at the same time, communicates via wireless signal *regardless of the power source or availability of a communication wire*, and has the battery lifetime to make it legal as opposed to one which is only designed as a short-term battery backup when not wired.

I don't know of any smoke detectors that fit this description.  Assuming it doesn't exist.  Should I just buy a bunch of battery-operated interconnects or ***`is there a compelling reason to hard-wire only a few with the hope of being able to expand the network during remodels in the future?`***

Comment: You should probably ask the inspector clarifying questions. If they’re mentioning interconnecting, it would be pretty shocking if they allowed two separate islands of alarms.

Comment: @nobody because there is currently no interconnection at all, therefore, he sees *anything* as an improvement, but he also understands that it isn't reasonable to demand for me to greatly expand the scope of my project for which the permit was pulled and essentially require that I rewire the entire house.

Answer (score 5):

### First Alert makes a wireless-to-wired bridge for their smoke alarms

If you use First Alert/BRK OneLink alarms for your wireless alarms and First Alert wired alarms, then you can use a First Alert SA520B at one of the hardwired locations as a "bridge" between the two setups.

Comment: I just did this with First Alert and I had a different company (forgot name) with the older alarms I replaced.   Pretty easy to do the plug conversion for the wired and have them connect to the other non-wired.

Answer (score 1):

Hardwired is the optimal solution, yes.

If you can only do wireless interconnect for whatever reason then at least run a dead wire to the smoke detector location(s) during the reno; 14/3 if I'm not mistaken. Label them "DEAD" at both ends and home-run them to a central junction box that is accessible in future renos.

After you renovate enough spaces then some day "future you" will thank "present you".

Answer (score 1):

In my area **the main objective of hard wiring is to provide power,** as some homeowners aren't very good at keeping batteries in their smoke alarms.

So it's completely acceptable to *power* the alarms from the lighting circuit (which is already in the ceiling in every room) and have all the alarms *interconnect* wirelessly.

Wired vs wireless interconnect is mostly a question of cost - wired interconnect alarms cost less, but you've got to run new cables as the interconnect needs a dedicated core. Wireless interconnect alarms cost a bit more upfront, but save on labour.